# How Can I pass a function in grandparent component to grandchild components in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to know how can I pass a function in grandparent component to grandchild components.
I have a function in Grandparent component which gets `id` and `slice()` that.
But id comes from a grandchild.
order is like this.

```
<Manager />
    <RecordList />
       <RecordItem />
```

when button clicked in  , it should give id to the function which comes from 

How can I do that **without** `Context API`?
and using **pass props down to child**

could you please make an example ?
Thank you all

Comment: Just pass all the props from grandparent component to grandchild component. What isn't working as you'd expect it to? Try to provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do and include details about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in React and can pass any data to any child nester under a particular component.

[Context API React](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

**EDIT**
Since you mentioned that you don't want to use Context API. For something like this, where the child is only one component deep, you can probably pass some props through the middle child. I will give you some rough ideas as it's impossible to write the entire since you wrote no code in the example.

```
<Manager>
    const childBtnClick = (params) => {
         // do you stuff here
    }
    <RecordList childBtnClick={childBtnClick}></RecordList>
</Manager>
<RecordList>
    <RecordItem childBtnClick={props.childBtnClick}></RecordItem>
</RecordList>
<RecordItem>
    <Button onClick={() => props.childBtnClick('passwhat data you want here')}></Button>
</RecordItem>
```

Comment: thanks for your help 
But I dont want to use Context API
Is there any other way??

Comment: The other way is to use pass props down your child or use Redux (not recommended)

Comment: Thank you 
What I want is to pass is like props from a child to grand child 
but I got error

Comment: Glad that I could help. @MojtabaSedighi